# EntitySqlException on select with code first dbcontext in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, sql, entity-framework, exception

#### When

```
var codeFirstRepositor = new Donors();
var list = codeFirstRepositor.CampaignReps.Select(c => c).ToList();
```

- When I put a breakpoint inside the `CampaignRep` class constructor it is not called at all - the exception seems to occur before object instantiation

#### Context

```
public class Donors : DbContext
{
    public Donors()
    {
        // Needed for WCF serialization to work
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }
    public DbSet<CampaignRep> CampaignReps { get; set; }
}
```

#### EntitySqlException

`'CampaignsReps' is not a member of Transient.collection[MyNameSpace.Donor(Nullable=True,DefaultValue=)]'. To extract a property of a collection element, use a subquery to iterate over the collection. Near escaped identifier, line 1, column 10.`

*What is the cause of this error?*

Comment: Why do you inherit the DbContext?  You could try to call `base()` in the constructor, but generally I see no reason to inherit...

Comment: @Trustme-I'maDoctor So you've used code first entity framework without inheriting DbContext?  I must admit I'm curious to see how you managed that.

Comment: @MalcolmO'Hare Ah, right... It's not `ObjectContext`. :) Nope, I've never used Code First approach, I'm a firm believer of database-first. And that would clarify a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the Select(c => c) and try again. Also, why do you even have that in your query?

Comment: the select was a relic and did not make a difference. i actually had some more DBSet properties (of other types) in the dbcontext which i thought were unrelated, but getting rid of them solved the problem?.. i am still to know what exactly the underlying issue was ...